# Android USB host Webcam

Tags: android, api, usb, webcam, host

I would like get the video stream from an usb webcam. 
I don't find example to use the USB host api.

So I would like to know if it's possible ?

Usb information of my webcam

```
046d:0825 Webcam C270 
Device : /dev/bus/usb/002/002 
Vendor : 0x046d Logitech, Inc. 
Product : 0x0825 Webcam C270 
Class : 0xef Miscellaneous Device 
SubClass : 0x02 ? 
Protocol : 0x01 Interface Association

Interface (1/19) 
Class : 0x0e Video 
SubClass : 0x01 Video Control 
Protocol : 0x00

Endpoint (1/1) 
Attr. : 0x87 (num=7,IN) 
Type : Interrupt 
Interval : 0x08 
Packsize : 0x0010 (16)

Interface (2/19) 
Class : 0x0e Video 
SubClass : 0x02 Video Streaming 
Protocol : 0x00

Interface (3/19) 
Class : 0x0e Video 
SubClass : 0x02 Video Streaming 
Protocol : 0x00

Endpoint (1/1) 
Attr. : 0x81 (num=1,IN) 
Type : Isochronous 
Interval : 0x01 
Packsize : 0x00c0 (192)
...
```

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the Webcam.